# LDAP - Authlogic

Tags: ruby, authentication, ldap

I have a ROR application with authlogic and LDAP, i follow the how to oh authologic and this http://pastie.org/385199 but the method (def valid_ldap_credentials?(password_plaintext)) is not called....any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to set `:validate_password_field => false`. My understanding is that this disables all password validation, so your custom method won't get called. Try taking that out and see what happens.

Also, the format appears incorrect -- Authlogic configuration options need to be done within a block like so:

```
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.validate_password_field = false
  end
```

Comment: acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :login
    c.validate_password_field = false
end

It works correctly, now i have to encrypt the password